# VB.NET - How to set max bytes to write in streamwriter with buffer

Tags: vb.net, file, stream

I have a stream writer that reads from one file and writes to the other with a buffer in the middle... i use fseek to seek to a byte position, however, it writes from byte position to end of file, I would like it to write from byte position to x amoutn of bytes.  How can i specify this? also, the files can be big, so math has to go via int64... here is the code:

```
 Dim bytesRead As Integer
        Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
        Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\some path\folder\file1.ext", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
  inFile.Seek(s, SeekOrigin.Current)
            Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\some path\folder\file2.ext", IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                Do
                    bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    If bytesRead > 0 Then
                        outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    End If
                Loop While bytesRead > 0
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: The Seek() call doesn't do anything useful.  It is unclear why you wouldn't just count the bytes you read and break out of the loop when it reaches X.  Just make the variable a Long.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans said, you'd need to track the total number of bytes you've read so far, which is the value returned by each call to Read(); just accumulate it in a variable.  You also need to account for the last "chunk" to read as it may be smaller than the size of your buffer.  This process could look something like...

```
    Dim StartAt As Int64 = 2000
    Dim NumBytesToCopy As Int64 = 10000
    Dim TotalBytesCopied As Int64 = 0

    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
    Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\some path\folder\file1.ext", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        inFile.Seek(StartAt, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\some path\folder\file2.ext", IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            Do
                If NumBytesToCopy - TotalBytesCopied < buffer.Length Then
                    ReDim buffer(NumBytesToCopy - TotalBytesCopied)
                End If

                bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                If bytesRead > 0 Then
                    outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    TotalBytesCopied = TotalBytesCopied + bytesRead
                End If
            Loop While bytesRead > 0 AndAlso TotalBytesCopied < NumBytesToCopy
        End Using
    End Using
```